# UPDATE rank in 3 ways within group

Tags: mysql, group-by

After searching and trying many examples, I couldn't get this figured out. 
Hope you can help me.

This is my table Test:

```
    +-------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------+
    |Id     |   Class   |   Score  |  Rank1  |  Rank2  | Rank3 |
    +-------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------+
    |1      |     1     |     9    |    0    |    0    |   0   |
    |2      |     1     |     9    |    0    |    0    |   0   |
    |3      |     1     |     8    |    0    |    0    |   0   |
    |4      |     1     |     7    |    0    |    0    |   0   |
    |5      |     2     |     9    |    0    |    0    |   0   |
    |6      |     2     |     8    |    0    |    0    |   0   |
    |7      |     2     |     8    |    0    |    0    |   0   |
    |8      |     2     |     7    |    0    |    0    |   0   |
    |9      |     2     |     6    |    0    |    0    |   0   |
    +-------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------+
```

What I would like is to UPDATE my table Test with 3 sorts of rankings:

1. = Rank 1 = Ranked on Score per Class with consecutive ranks (no double)
2. = Rank 2 = Ranked on Score per Class with consecutive ranks (with double)
3. = Rank 3 = Ranked on Score per Class without consecutive ranks (with double)

E.g:

```
    +-------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------+
    |Id     |   Class   |   Score  |  Rank1  |  Rank2  | Rank3 |
    +-------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------+
    |1      |     1     |     9    |    1    |    1    |   1   |
    |2      |     1     |     9    |    2    |    1    |   1   |
    |3      |     1     |     8    |    3    |    2    |   3   |
    |4      |     1     |     7    |    4    |    3    |   4   |
    |5      |     2     |     9    |    1    |    1    |   1   |
    |6      |     2     |     8    |    2    |    2    |   2   |
    |7      |     2     |     8    |    3    |    2    |   2   |
    |8      |     2     |     7    |    4    |    3    |   4   |
    |9      |     2     |     6    |    5    |    4    |   5   |
    +-------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------+
```

NOTE: it has to be applicable within a UPDATE statement.

For 1. I have found (but can't figure out how to make it an UPDATE):

```
SET @prev := null;
SET @cnt := 0;
SELECT IF(@prev <> Class, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS Rank, @prev := Class
FROM Test
ORDER BY Class;
```

For 3. I have found (but can't figure out how to make it an UPDATE):

```
SELECT  a.Id,
    a.Score,
    a.Class,
    count(b.Score)+1 as Rank
FROM    Test a left join Test b 
    on a.Score>b.Score and a.Class=b.Class 
GROUP BY    a.Id,
        a.Score,
        a.Class;
```

I've added the results when based Score on values with decimals. Strange rankings appear:

```
SET @prev_class = 0,@class = 0,@prev_score = 0,@score = 0,@rank3 = 0,@count=0;
UPDATE 1i SET
   Score_pq_raw_rank = (@prev_class := IFNULL(@class,0)),
   Score_pq_raw_rank = (@class := Profile_id),
   Score_pq_raw_rank = (@prev_score := IFNULL(@score,-1)),
   Score_pq_raw_rank = (@score := Score_pq_raw),
   Score_pq_raw_rank = (
   CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @rank3 := 1
        WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score = @score THEN @rank3
        WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score != @score THEN @rank3:=@rank3+1+@count
   END),
   Score_pq_raw_rank = (CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @count := 0
        WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score = @score THEN @count := @count + 1
        WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score != @score THEN @count := 0
   END),
   Score_pq_raw_rank = @rank3
ORDER BY Profile_id ASC, Score_pq_raw DESC, Rowresult_id ASC;

+--------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+
| Rowresult_id | Score_pq_raw | Profile_id | Score_pq_raw_rank |
+--------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+
|            1 | 3.69054000   |          1 |                 1 |
|            2 | 0.10568000   |          1 |                 2 |
|            3 | -2.08058000  |          1 |                 3 |
|            4 | -2.07316000  |          1 |                 3 |
|            5 | -2.39066000  |          1 |                 3 |
|            6 | -10.23852000 |          2 |                 3 |
|            7 | -8.77718000  |          2 |                 2 |
|            8 | -7.38480000  |          2 |                 1 |
|            9 | -13.49128000 |          2 |                 4 |
|           10 | -19.36774000 |          2 |                 5 |
+--------------+--------------+------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: What SQL statements have you tried?

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived data

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the select that gives you your wanted ranks.

```
SELECT Id,Class,Score,
       @prev_class := IFNULL(@class,0),
       @class := Class,
       @prev_score := IFNULL(@score,-1),
       @score := Score,

       CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @rank1 := 1
            ELSE @rank1 := @rank1 + 1
       END as rank1,
       CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @rank2 := 1
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score = @score THEN @rank2
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score != @score THEN @rank2:=@rank2+1
       END as rank2,
       CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @rank3 := 1
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score = @score THEN @rank3
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score != @score THEN @rank3:=@rank3+1+@count
       END as rank3,
       CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @count := 0
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score = @score THEN @count := @count + 1
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score != @score THEN @count := 0
       END as count
FROM Test
ORDER BY Class ASC, Score DESC, Id ASC;
```

and here's the UPDATE that'll do that work, I just use SET rank1 multiple times because mysql doesn't seem to allow you just set @variables without using the result for some columns...

```
SET @prev_class = 0,@rank1 = 0,@score = 0,@prev_score = 0,@class =0,@rank2=0,@rank3 =0,@count=0;
UPDATE Test SET
       rank1 = (@prev_class := IFNULL(@class,0)),
       rank1 = (@class := Class),
       rank1 = (@prev_score := IFNULL(@score,-1)),
       rank1 = (@score := Score),
       rank1 = (
       CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @rank1 := 1
            ELSE @rank1 := @rank1 + 1
       END),
       rank2 = (
       CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @rank2 := 1
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score = @score THEN @rank2
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score != @score THEN @rank2:=@rank2+1
       END),
       rank3 = (
       CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @rank3 := 1
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score = @score THEN @rank3
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score != @score THEN @rank3:=@rank3+1+@count
       END),
       rank3 = (CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @count := 0
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score = @score THEN @count := @count + 1
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score != @score THEN @count := 0
       END),
       rank3 = @rank3
ORDER BY Class ASC, Score DESC, Id ASC
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d27f/1)

**Update rank1 only**

```
SET @prev_class = 0,@class = 0,@prev_score = 0,@score = 0,@rank1 = 0;
UPDATE Test SET
       rank1 = (@prev_class := IFNULL(@class,0)),
       rank1 = (@class := Class),
       rank1 = (@prev_score := IFNULL(@score,-1)),
       rank1 = (@score := Score),
       rank1 = (
       CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @rank1 := 1
            ELSE @rank1 := @rank1 + 1
       END)
ORDER BY Class ASC, Score DESC, Id ASC;
```

**Update rank2 only**

```
SET @prev_class = 0,@class = 0,@prev_score = 0,@score = 0,@rank2 = 0;
UPDATE Test SET
       rank2 = (@prev_class := IFNULL(@class,0)),
       rank2 = (@class := Class),
       rank2 = (@prev_score := IFNULL(@score,-1)),
       rank2 = (@score := Score),
       rank2 = (
       CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @rank2 := 1
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score = @score THEN @rank2
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score != @score THEN @rank2:=@rank2+1
       END)
ORDER BY Class ASC, Score DESC, Id ASC;
```

**Update rank3 only**

```
SET @prev_class = 0,@class = 0,@prev_score = 0,@score = 0,@rank3 = 0,@count=0;
UPDATE Test SET
       rank3 = (@prev_class := IFNULL(@class,0)),
       rank3 = (@class := Class),
       rank3 = (@prev_score := IFNULL(@score,-1)),
       rank3 = (@score := Score),
       rank3 = (
       CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @rank3 := 1
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score = @score THEN @rank3
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score != @score THEN @rank3:=@rank3+1+@count
       END),
       rank3 = (CASE WHEN @prev_class != @class THEN @count := 0
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score = @score THEN @count := @count + 1
            WHEN @prev_class = @class AND @prev_score != @score THEN @count := 0
       END),
       rank3 = @rank3
ORDER BY Class ASC, Score DESC, Id ASC;
```

Comment: This is fenominal!! 
Now because some of my DB's need rank1, others rank 2 etc I can't figure out how to UPDATE each rank separately. I've cut some parts, but only updates a 0. Could you help me with slicing them in to 3 separate ranking UPDATE or maybe point me in the right way how to?

Comment: you want to be able to update each rank separately like 3 different updates?

Comment: If this is possible, by having this for some db this would be very helpfull

Comment: wait a bit i'll update my answer to include 3 more updates

Comment: Works beautifully, many thanks!!
Note: Update rank2 only missed the last line of ORDER BY...

Comment: Hi @Tin Tran I'm using the raking in full, but not I've stumbled upon a possible 'error'. When I'm using a ranking method but with a Score of let's say 1,1234 or -0.1234 the ranking I think rounds the score in some way. So 1,123 would get the same ranking as 1,124. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: post another question with your test data... i don't think rounding would cause such error

Comment: in the `SET` statement at the beginning instead of `@prev_score = 0` and `@score = 0`  use `@prev_score = 0.0` and `@score = 0.0`  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2461ca/1

Comment: Once again, superb!! I've spend hours on debugging in my side, but this wasn't something I've expected. Many thanks (again).